# How to access Picasa Web albums data api from Web application using 2 legged OAuth

Tags: jakarta-ee, oauth-2.0, google-api-java-client, picasa

I want users in my application to be able to upload photos and read photos from there in my picasa account.I dont want them to redirect for authentication.I see that i can use 2 Legged  OAuth for this.What all need to be done to use the 2 Legged OAuth in my webapp. Do i have to generate some key in Google data console.

Also what is the best approach for my web application for accessing/posting photos to Picasa web album.Is using the GET/POST url's the best approach.If so how will the OAuth 2 Legged authentication can be used in this approach.

Comment: The whole point of three-legged authorization is that your web app does not get its hands on the users' passwords. If you want two-legged authorization, you have to pursuade your users to give you their picasa cendentials. That requires a lot of trust.

Comment: I don't want user's credentials.The web app will be using a single picasa account which belongs to me.In this case i dont want the redirect to happen.Is it possible